# itemSelectionChanged not firing a signal

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've created this whole thing with ChatGPT so I don't have much knowledge on how each individual part works but essentially whenever I click on a "tag" in the list widget, I want it to add/remove that "tag" to from a "global array" which I believe is called "self.tags".

```
import sys
import sqlite3


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTextStream, QFile, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton,
                             QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QListWidget, QLineEdit, QSplitter)


class ImageTagger(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.tags = []
        # Create a label to display the image
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Create a list widget to display the tags
        self.tag_list = QListWidget()
        self.tag_list.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.MultiSelection)
        self.tag_list.itemClicked.connect(self.updateSelectedTags)

        # Create a line edit for the search bar
        self.search_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.search_bar.textChanged.connect(self.searchTags)

        # Create a button to select the folder
        self.select_folder_button = QPushButton("Select Folder")
        self.select_folder_button.clicked.connect(self.selectFolder)

        # Create a button to save the tags
        self.save_tags_button = QPushButton("Save Tags")
        self.save_tags_button.clicked.connect(self.saveTags)

        # Create a button to go to the next image
        self.next_button = QPushButton("Next")
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.nextImage)

        # Create a button to go to the previous image
        self.prev_button = QPushButton("Prev")
        self.prev_button.clicked.connect(self.prevImage)

        # Create a vertical layout to hold the search bar and tag list
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.search_bar)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tag_list)

        # Create a horizontal layout to hold the buttons
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.select_folder_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.save_tags_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.prev_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.next_button)

        # Add the layouts to a widget
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

        # Create a splitter to split the main layout into two parts
        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(self.image_label)
        splitter.addWidget(widget)

        # Set the sizes of the widgets in the splitter
        splitter.setSizes([600, 200])

        # Add the splitter and the hbox layout to the main layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
        main_layout.addLayout(hbox)

        # Create a central widget and set its layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Set the central widget as the central widget of the main window
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Load the tags from the database
        self.loadTags()

        # Set the main window properties
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image Tagger")

    def selectFolder(self):
        # Show the "Select Folder" dialog and get the selected folder
        folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Folder")
        if folder:
            # Set the current folder
            self.current_folder = folder
            # Get the list of images in the folder
            self.image_list = [f for f in os.listdir(self.current_folder) if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png")]
            # Set the current image index to the first image
            self.current_image_index = 0
            # Display the first image
            self.displayImage()
        # Clear the list of tags
        self.tag_list.clear()

        # Load the tags from the database
        self.loadTags()

    def displayImage(self):
        try:
            # Load the image file
            image_file_path = os.path.join(self.current_folder, self.image_list[self.current_image_index])
            image = QPixmap(image_file_path)
            # Display the image
            max_size = self.image_label.maximumSize()
            scaled_image = image.scaled(max_size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(image))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading image: {e}")
            self.image_label.setText("Error loading image")


    def saveTags(self):
        # Get the list of selected tags
        selected_tags = [self.tag_list.item(i).text() for i in range(self.tag_list.count()) if
                         self.tag_list.item(i).isSelected()]
        # Join the tags into a single string
        tags_string = ", ".join(selected_tags)
        # Get the name of the current image file
        image_file_name = self.image_list[self.current_image_index]
        # Create the name of the text file
        text_file_name = os.path.splitext(image_file_name)[0] + ".txt"
        # Open the text file for writing
        with open(os.path.join(self.current_folder, text_file_name), "w") as f:
            # Write the tags to the text file
            f.write(tags_string)

    def nextImage(self):
        # Increment the current image index
        self.current_image_index += 1
        # If the index is out of range, wrap around to the first image
        if self.current_image_index >= len(self.image_list):
            self.current_image_index = 0
        # Display the image
        self.displayImage()

    def prevImage(self):
        # Decrement the current image index
        self.current_image_index -= 1
        # If the index is out of range, wrap around to the last image
        if self.current_image_index < 0:
            self.current_image_index = len(self.image_list) - 1
        # Display the image
        self.displayImage()

    def loadTags(self):
        # Check if the current folder is set
        if not hasattr(self, 'current_folder'):
            return

        # Connect to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(self.current_folder, "tags.db"))
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Load the tags from the database
        c.execute("SELECT tag FROM tags")
        tags = c.fetchall()

        # Add the tags to the list widget
        self.tag_list.clear()
        for tag in tags:
            self.tag_list.addItem(tag[0])

        # Sort the tags alphabetically
        self.tags = sorted(tags)

        # Close the connection to the database
        conn.close()


    def searchTags(self):
        # Get the search string
        search_text = self.search_bar.text()

        # Clear the list widget
        self.tag_list.clear()
        try:
            # Iterate through the tags and add the ones that contain the search string
            for tag in self.tags:
                if search_text.lower() in tag[0].lower():
                    self.tag_list.addItem(tag[0])
        except Exception as e:
            # Print the error message
            print(e)

    def updateSelectedTags(self):
        # Get the list of selected items in the list widget
        selected_items = self.tag_list.selectedItems()

        # Clear the list of selected tags
        self.tags.clear()

        # Add the text of each selected item to the list of selected tags
        for item in selected_items:
            self.tags.append(item.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ImageTagger()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The reason why I am doing this is because when the .db file is loaded and stored into a tag_list array and when I click on a tag in the list widget then type any character in the search bar it forgets/replaces the tags that I previously clicked. I have NO CLUE why the `self.tag_list.itemClicked.connect(self.updateSelectedTags)` signal isn't firing (or at least the debug isn't catching it)

I'm done ripping me hair out over this. I would appreciate any help or a better method of doing this. ChatGPT can only help so much.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your issue. With the current selection mode, if you press a key that corresponds to the first letter of an item, it will toggle the current selection (just like clicking it): the behavior is visible in the current selection *and* is also printed in the output with the updated list. You're also referring to a "search bar", but there's no trace of it in your code. Besides, even if ChatGPT is an extremely powerful tool, it doesn't yet replace proper programming, which **always** involves understanding the code and studying the documentation of what you're using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was so tired and upset at staying up all night that I ended up posting an earlier version of the code. I have changed the code above to reflect that. However, I found the problem now.
What happened was I had all my backup .py's in the same folder incase ChatGPT went wild and at some point I must have been editing/setting my breakpoint in the sacrificial program and when it came time to click the debug button for some reason Pycharm was debugging one of my backups which explains why the itemClicked.connect NEVER stopped the program. I was running the wrong instance the whole time!

Comment: Based on your latest update, `updateSelectedTags` is correctly called whenever an item is clicked, but then you have multiple issues in your code. For instance, when you load the tags, you store them as they are read from the database (a list of tuples), but when `updateSelectedTags` you clear the list and replace it with a list of strings. This is one of the reasons for which blindly following what an experimental and general purpose AI suggests is wrong: while its input may be useful, you must understand its context and be aware that it doesn't always provide *correct* code.